# How do I executed a function for specific seconds

Tags: android, bluetooth

So basically, I want to stream data from bluetooth but with on-off mode. Each on & off mode happened for a specific amount of time, i.e 5 seconds.
So,
I need to put a function to executed for a 5 seconds and then executed another function inside a button click method. But my code below doesn't work as it should be.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOn);                  // button LED ON
        btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOff);                // button LED OFF
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        txtArduino = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtArduino);      // for display the received data from the Arduino

        h = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // if receive massage
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array
                    sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
                    int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // if end-of-line,
                        String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                        txtArduino.setText("Data from Arduino: " + sbprint);            // update TextView
                        btnOff.setEnabled(true);
                        btnOn.setEnabled(true); 
                    }
                    //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                    break;
                }
            };
        };

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
        checkBTState();

        btnOn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            btnOn.setEnabled(false);
            bluetoothConnect();
          }
        });

        btnOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            btnOff.setEnabled(false);  
            bluetoothDisconnect();
          }
        });

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                bluetoothDisconnect();
                    //Starts from here the code doesn't work
                    //I want to perform these functions over and over
                while (true){
                    //I want method executed for 5 seconds here
                    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            bluetoothConnect();
                        }
                    }, 5000);
                    //I want method executed for 5 seconds here
                    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            bluetoothDisconnect();
                        }
                    }, 5000);
                }
              }
            });
      }
```

Comment: whats the use-case for this? in any case, postDelayed means "in 5000ms, run this code", so its not really what you're looking for. I think the only way you could do it would be with some sort of interrupt. However there is no guarantee that the data you're sending over bluetooth would send correctly in the 5 seconds you're giving it, which could cause data corruption issues.

Comment: i put the buffer data in a thread, so everytime the bluetooth socket connected the data streamed as well. Do you have any link for the specific interrupt that i can use here?

Comment: I still don't get why you're limiting it to 5 seconds runtime

Comment: Because I want to turning On & Off bluetooth over and over. I want to check the data corruption & power consumption when bluetooth set to idle mode with this On-Off mode. It's for the sake of my research. The duty cycle of on-off may vary, not just 5 second.

Comment: If you're running the Bluetooth handling code in a separate thread (which you should be), then you could probably use Thread.interrupt() to tell the Bluetooth thread to stop all processing (I believe).

Comment: I still don't get it, I'm new to Android programming, could you give me the example or link related, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way...

```
private boolean canExecute;

private void callYourMethod() {
    canExecute = true;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            canExecute = false;
        }
    }, 5000);
    yourMethodToExecuteForFiveSeconds();
}

private void yourMethodToExecuteForFiveSeconds() {
    // Your code goes here

    if (canExecute) {
        //This will be true for five seconds only.
        yourMethodToExecuteForFiveSeconds();
    }
}
```

Comment: hey it's not working, what do you mean by calling the function inside their own method? private void yourMethodToExecuteForFiveSeconds() {
    // Your code goes here

    if (canExecute) {
        //This will be true for five seconds only.
        yourMethodToExecuteForFiveSeconds();
    }
}